# How to decode some special fonts in a pdf using xpdf?

Tags: php, type-conversion, shellexecute, pdftotext

I am using xpdf to convert pdf files to text.
Below is the code used for it.

```
$content = shell_exec('pdftotext '.$filename.' -');
```

Xpdf is not able to convert few special fonts in pdf to text.
for example: bizarre font cannot be converted to text using xpdf.

Are they any alternative software which can convert all kind of fonts in pdf to text in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try the [**Poppler**](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) version of `pdftotext` if the XPDF version fails for your files....

**However, take note of this fact, please:** ***Not even Acrobat Reader can extract all cases of well rendered text on a PDF page to a text file...***